# PHP how to paginate an Array

Tags: arrays, key, pagination

Hello how to Order my array new from

```
array(2=>'test',5=>'bla',333=>'finish')
```

to

```
array(0=>'test',1=>'bla',2=>'finish')
```

Comment: What do you want when saying _paginate_? I think you just want to re-index the array with a ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_values` : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php

```
array_values(array(2=>'test',5=>'bla',333=>'finish'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function, just read the docs